# Hide passwords for MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, encryption, passwords

**I've found many questions on this topic, and many answers, but none that suited my situation. If I have missed one or two, feel free to refer me to a suitable one. Please bare in mind that I only have basic knowledge of Java, and am always willing to learn new things, as long as they are properly explained.**

I recently started writing a Java Application, requiring a secure login. I figured the best way to do this (for multiple users) was to use a MySQL database on a server I had full access to (in other words, my RaspBerry Pi). I've got the database set up correctly, and have created the user account I wish to use for the purpose of requesting data.

When the user opens the application, it checks whether the application has access to the internet (by pinging multiple websites), and whether the application has access to the server (by pinging the server itself). The location of the server and database can be disclosed. When both connections are confirmed, the application will start, asking the user for a username and a password, stored in the MySQL database.

The real problem is connecting to the database, without having people find other people's passwords. I don't want some kid to decompile my application and get all of the usernames and passwords stored in the database. How will I securely gain access to my database (meaning, how will I connect to it without the username and password being visible)? I'm also hoping to store the passwords in the database in encrypted form, decrypting them after they are retrieved. The most important issue is making sure nobody can decompile the application, find out how I did it, and do it themselves, giving them all the information I tried to hide.

Comment: store hash of password instead of plain text or encrypted passwords

Comment: I'm curious what you've found in your searches, since this is a pretty common question, not only here but also on other sites. Can you tell us how the solutions that you have found don't work for you? Otherwise, you'll be asking us to re-write much that has already been written, and written well.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Most of what I found was using an encryption password, which had to be stored in the application, therefor allowing anyone else to decrypt it in the same way as me. I also found that people would store passwords in their encrypted form in a properties file, which would then be protected by the operating system in the form of file permissions, but those are easily crackable using simple applications, if not just your computer's terminal. A third common solution was some sort of web query, which I'm not at all familiar with, meaning I don't see that working out well.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to have each user enter their own password instead of sharing it as part of the application.  It has the additional advantage of being able to block an individual user's access when necessary without redistributing your application.

Whether you cache their password in the application on individual's computers or make them enter it each time is up to your level of paranoia.

Comment: And yes, make sure that the passwords on the server are hashed and the connection is over SSL.  MySQL has builtin functions for password hashing.  Let the server do the encrypt/decrypt so if someone get's access to the table, they just see the encrypted values.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know too much about Java yet, which is why I'm learning. Could you give me a link to a tutorial about how to do that?

Comment: I've now got it set up so it stores encrypted passwords in the database, and matches them to the encrypted version of the passwords users enter, but I still have no idea how to hide the password I use to connect to the database..